# MYSQL Add Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add a constraint to my two tables, but I can't remember what the correct syntax is. Below are the two tables,

[image]

Is it.........

```
ALTER TABLE dispatch ADD CONSTRAINT fk_productlines FOREIGN KEY
(productlines_fkid) REFERENCES productlines(fkid)
```

Is that right? 
When I try

```
ALTER TABLE dispatch ADD CONSTRAINT fk_productlines FOREIGN KEY
(fkid) REFERENCES productlines(fkid)
```

I get the following message:

```
#1072 - Key column 'fkid' doesn't exist in table
```

Comment: If you cannot remember syntax - check it in documentation.

Comment: There's documentation for "I can't remember syntax", no need to post on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `productlines.fkid` a primary key ?

To make it a `foreign key` in `dispatch` it must be a `primary key` of `productlines`

To add a foreign key in dispatch :

```
ALTER TABLE dispatch 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_productlines 
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES productlines(fkid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE product_lines ADD CONSTRAINT fk_productlines FOREIGN KEY
(fkid) REFERENCES dispatch(ID)
```

That should work.. Try it yourself!

Comment: At first yeah, but now I modified it a bit.. :D

Comment: How OP is supposed to find the difference if you haven't noticed that?